# Solving non-linear system of equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I encountered a non-linear system of equations that has to be solved.
The system of equations can be written as:
`Ax + exp(x) = b` with `b` a known `Nx1` matrix, `A` a known `NxN` matrix, and `x` the unknown `Nx1` vector for which has to be solved. The `exp` is defined element-wise on the `x` vector. I tried to search the MATLAB-manual but I'm having a hard time finding how to solve this kind of equations with MATLAB, so I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Explain please, what does notation exp(x) mean? Does the exponent act on the whole vector or on some of its elements?

Comment: Ah, I mean that if for instance x = [1; 2; 3], then exp(x) = [exp(1); exp(2); exp(3)]. So it is acting on each element separately. (Instead of the conventional definition of the exponential of a matrix: exp(A) = 1+A+A^2/2+..., which is not what I want to do here :))

Comment: Are you allowed to use any of the optimization or curve fitting functions available in MATLAB?

Comment: I solved this in your original post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462386/solving-non-linear-system-of-equations-with-matlab/2365469.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Newton-Raphson.  Re-arrange your system into a zero residual:

```
R = A * x + exp(x) - b
```

Then take the derivative of `R` with respect to `x`:

```
dRdx = A + diag(exp(x))
```

Then iterate.  An example is shown below:

```
n = 3;

a = rand(n, n);
b = rand(n, 1);

% solve a * x + exp(x) = b for x

x = zeros(n, 1);

for itr = 1: 10
    x = x - (a + diag(exp(x))) \ (a * x + exp(x) - b);
end
```

Of course, you could make this more intelligent by stopping iteration after the residual is small enough.

Comment: It's even more intelligent to calculate increments `Dx` of `x`, then do `x=x+Dx` and stop if `Dx` is small enough. This avoids some numerical problems and the stopping criterion is affine invariant.

Comment: @Wauzl  Good point.  But rather than writing our own fancy NR implementations, it would be better to use MATLAB's `fsolve` with a function that returns both the residual and the Jacobian.  [Like this example, but without the sparsity.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-equations-with-jacobian.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Not quite. If you really want Newton-Raphson, then you have to implement it yourself, because `fsolve` uses optimization techniques, which means it solves something like `|F(x)|^2 -> min` instead of `F(x) = 0`. But if you just have to solve on equation one time, then you should probably go with `fsolve`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it iteratively starting with the solution of the linearized system `[A+1]x(0)=b-1` as an initial guess, where 1 is an identity matrix. At the each step of the iterative procedure I would add the exponential of the previous solution at the right-hand side: `Ax(j)=b-exp(x(j-1))`

Comment: This is the right idea, but I think you went wrong somewhere in the linearization.  For your initial guess, how do you calculate `b-1`?  This doesn't make sense if `1` is the identity matrix.

Comment: Expansion of the exponent in Taylor series

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this is a cross post.

This is my solution for the [other posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365469/33):

The function can be written in the form:

$$ f \left( x \right) = A x + \exp \left( x \right) - b $$

Which is equivalent to the above once a root of $ f \left( x \right) $ is found.
One could use [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for root finding.

The [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) (Like the Transpose of Gradient) of $ f \left( x \right) $ is given by:

$$ J \left( f \left( x \right) \right) = A + diag \left( \exp \left( x \right) \right) $$

Hence the newton iteration is given by:

$$ {x}^{k + 1} = {x}^{k} - { J \left( f \left( {x}^{k} \right) \right) }^{-1} f \left( {x}^{k} \right) $$

You can see the code in my [Mathematics Q1462386 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q1462386) which includes both analytic and numerical derivation of the Jacobian.

This is the result of one run:

[image]

Pay attention that while it finds a root for this problem there are more than 1 root hence the solution is one of many and depends on the initial point.